# Value of $\lambda$ in Boundary value problem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Determine the values of $\lambda \in R$ such that the BVP

$$ \frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}+\lambda u=0$$

where $u(0)=0$ and $u(1)=0$, has a non zero solution.

I am not able to proceed in this particular question. Can someone give some hint?

Comment: Set $u = e^{mx}$, substitute into your ODE, find an explicit solution, show it is non-zero.

Comment: But $u(0)=0$. Can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: The general solution will be $$u(x) = C \sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x) + D \cos(\sqrt{\lambda} x)$$ What does $u(0)$ equal in this equation?

Comment: He is asking for a hint guys not for a complete answer...come on let people work alone !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}+\lambda u=0$$

Let $u=e^{mx}$ be the trial solution.

Hence we have that, $$\frac{du}{dx}=me^{mx}$$ and $$\frac{d^2 u}{dx^2}=m^2e^{mx}$$

So the differential equation becomes $$(m^2+\lambda)e^{mx}=0$$
$$\Rightarrow (m^2+\lambda)u=0$$

Hence we have that $$m=\pm i\sqrt{\lambda}$$

So the general solution is $$u=Ae^{i\sqrt{\lambda}x}+Be^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}x}$$
which boils down to the following using Euler's Theorem,

$$u=A(\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x+i\sin \sqrt{\lambda}x)+B(\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x-i\sin \sqrt{\lambda}x)$$ or
$$u=(A+B)\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x+(A-B)i\sin \sqrt{\lambda}x$$ or 
$$u=C\cos \sqrt{\lambda}x+D\sin \sqrt{\lambda}x$$

Now using $u(0)=0$ and $u(1)=0$, we have that 
$$0=C$$ and $$0=C\cos \sqrt{\lambda}+D\sin \sqrt{\lambda}$$
which implies both $C,D$ are $0$ or $C=0$ and $\sqrt\lambda=n\pi$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

First condition is not possible, so only possible case is the second one.

Required general solution is $u=D\sin \sqrt{\lambda}x$ only if $\lambda=n^2\pi^2$.

That is, $$u=D\sin n\pi x$$   where $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: How about $\lambda=\pi^2 k^2,\,k\in\mathbb Z$?

Comment: @Artem Yes I think you are right.

Comment: @Artem Thanks for helping. Is it okay now?

Comment: To be "totally OK", you need to specify which $n$ you can take. A little thought should show that only $n=1,2,\ldots$ produce nontrivial different solutions.

Comment: @Artem I have mentioned that. Please check .

Comment: @SchrodingersCat First, $n\notin \mathbb Z$ because, e.g., for $n=0$ the solution is trivial, and for $n=-1$ the solution is the same as for $n=1$. Second, if you think that I downvoted your answer, this is also incorrect, so I cannot revert this -1 :)

Comment: @Artem I don't care who gave the downvote ... So you can forget about it. ..:) .  Moreover, my solutions include both trivial and non-trivial solutions together and there is no restriction for distinct solutions. So why should I not consider $n=-1$?

Comment: Note that the OP is asking only about non zero solutions, this eliminates 0.  Your $n=-1$ gives exactly the same $\lambda$ and the same solution, hence can be dropped as well.

Comment: @Artem Okay point taken.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

$$\frac{\text{d}^2u(x)}{\text{d}x^2}+\lambda u(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$u''(x)+\lambda u(x)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Assume the solution will be proportional to $e^{x\mu}$ for some constant $\mu$.

Substitute $u(x)=e^{x\mu}$ into the differential equation:

---

$$\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}x^2}\left(e^{x\mu}\right)+\lambda e^{x\mu}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Substitute $\frac{\text{d}^2}{\text{d}x^2}\left(e^{x\mu}\right)=\mu^2e^{x\mu}$:

---

$$\mu^2e^{x\mu}+\lambda e^{x\mu}=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$e^{x\mu}\left(\mu^2+\lambda\right)=0\Longleftrightarrow$$

---

Since $e^{x\mu}\ne0$ for any finite $\mu$, the zeros must come from the polynomial:

---

$$\mu^2+\lambda=0\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\mu=\pm i\sqrt{\lambda}$$

Answer (score 0):

The simple harmonic oscillation equation has solution

$$ u(x) = A \sin(\sqrt{\lambda} x) + B \cos(\sqrt{\lambda} $$

From first boundary condition an odd solution is chosen. In frequency form

$$ \omega =  \frac{2 \pi}{T} $$

$$ A \sin {\sqrt \lambda} x =    A \sin \frac{2 \pi x }{T }   $$

The $\lambda $ here should not be confused with the time period.

You gave $ T=2 $ for one sine wave  ( double between successive roots) so that by comparing

$$ \lambda = \pi^2  $$

for first wave and in general when more waves are included for arcsin solution

$$ \lambda = (n \pi) ^2. $$